# Empty ObjectFactory constructor is critical issue in Sonar

Tags: java, jaxb, sonarqube

My ObjectFactory is generated from schema with JAXB plugin, so I cannot write extra code inside of it's empty constructor.

```
public ObjectFactory() {
}
```

This is critical issue in SonarQube. How can this be fixed or at least ignored?

```
Add a nested comment explaining why this method is empty, throw an UnsupportedOperationException or complete the implementation.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should probably exclude generated sources from the analysis.

See the documentation for how to do this : http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Narrowing+the+Focus